# openCV4Android v.3.0.0 hand sign recognition in Java

Tags: java, android, opencv

I would like to write an application on Android, which recognise a sign, in my case alphabet. I have done detection a hand (background substraction), with find biggest contours, convex hull and convexity defects. Is's working like that:

http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14372366211928362.png

I was reading about K-Nearest Neighborhood, but how to train date? In Android version of openCV I found method findNearest(Mat samples, int k, Mat results, Mat neighborResponses, Mat dist), but I have no idea how to use that. Anybody help me?